# Delete data held by UK immigration?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

I have a feeling that getting something in my UK immigration data deleted is about as easy as walking through a brick wall, but maybe I'm wrong. Has anybody ever tried?

I have a UK passport. About 8 years ago, I left the UK by ferry and the departure was not recorded. When I returned by plane to Stansted, I was kept waiting for about 20 minutes while the immigration officer checked this "irregularity", then he let me enter. It seems he wrote something in my record like "arrived in UK without apparently having left UK". When I arrive in the UK, I can see that they notice this, but the official just taps a couple more keys, presumably to see if I'm in the police database, and then lets me in. But when I took a train from Hungary (EU) to Ukraine (non-EU), I was flagged by the Hungarian officer with a hand-held computer, made to sit in the immigration police office for about an hour while they checked, and when they let me go, of course the train had left (and there aren't many trains or buses a day in those parts). So presumably the Schengen Information System is linked to UK immigration. Last time I was in Ukraine, it would have been nice to take the bus to Slovakia, but it wouldn't have been so nice to sit in the Slovak police office for an hour, so of course I didn't take the chance.

Thanks for the comments, everyone. 1. AFAIK, eight years ago, the ferry companies sent in passenger lists to the authorities for each trip. I arrived at the ferry at the very last minute, presumably after they'd made up or sent off their list. 2. Surely the information held has to be an exact match and include the passport number? Otherwise if someone with a common name like John Taylor is wanted for murder, there will be several other blokes with that name and the same date of birth who will get flagged and maybe even detained. 3. Of course I can't be 100% certain that the incident in Hungary was related, but I've travelled all over the world and never had any problems with immigration or law enforcement anywhere. 4. I'd be interested to know if something similar has happened to other people. There must be others who "arrive in the UK without having left the UK", such as those who have their own boat, people with dual nationality, etc.

Comment: Do you think the information is incorrect? How do you know the incident in Hungary was related?

Comment: Why do you think that they are storing data of UK citizens at all?  This data collection started in 2015 (4 years ago) and aimed at non EEA Citizens. What efforts have you undertaken? https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-32205970

Comment: Just a note, but you don't get data *deleted*, you get it *corrected* - if you ask for UK immigration data to be deleted, you are almost certainly going to get a "nope, we have a valid reason to retain that data indefinitely" and nothing short of a court order is going to shift them on that.  However, if you request for a *correction* and provide a good evidentially backed case, its likely that they will act on it.

Comment: It could be that on the UK database there is someone with the same (or very similar name) with the same (or close) date of birth. It's a long shot but if that person is also on SIS it could be that you are delayed in order for the officers to confirm you are not the person they are interested in.

Comment: The [UK is connected to SISII](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/second-generation-schengen-information-system-sisii) but only for law enforcement purposes. You can make a Subject Access Request: the details are in the document linked here.

Comment: Something sounds odd to me in this story. 8 years ago, there were AFAIK no exit checks when leaving the UK, be it by ferry nor plane. A situation as in 'arrived in UK without apparently having left UK' would have been the norm and not an exception.

Comment: I have edited my post to reply as there seems to be a word limit on comments.

Comment: Out of the box solution: check if you're eligible for an Irish passport and get one, if possible. This should let you travel on a "clean" document and would be useful post-Brexit :)

Comment: "arrived in UK without apparently having left UK" wouldn't this be a usual case for dual citizens? (I normally fly out on my other passport, but always coming back to the UK I show the immigration my UK passport with no questions asked) unless I am somehow linked in their system and they can see all my departures and arrivals with all my passports.

Comment: @kiradotee you're supposed to leave and enter on the same passport. If you're UK/South African and fly London-Jo'burg, you leave the UK on your UK passport, enter the RSA on your RSA passport, leave the RSA on your RSA passport, and enter the UK again on your UK passport.

Comment: @jwenting UK doesn't make it easy because of the no exit checks. That would mean going to South Africa I have to check in as British and not as South African.

Comment: I didn't post this because it was a big problem for me, but more out of curiosity. I used to travel a lot, but mostly to non-EU countries, but now I'm getting old and it's no big deal if I never set foot in the Schengen area again. If I decide to do so, I'll probably wait until the UK has left the EU, because then it seems likely that I will have to apply for a visa waiver and any "irregularity" will presumably be checked at that stage, so when I arrive at an EU airport, it should be plain sailing.

Comment: "Otherwise if someone with a common name like John Taylor is wanted for murder, there will be several other blokes with that name and the same date of birth who will get flagged and maybe even detained. " Yes. So? That's not a problem for the immigration authorities.

Answer (score 4):

It is far from certain that you have a 'wrong' entry. You only have two incidents over many years, one of which was trivial. You have no real reason to think they are even connected, let alone caused by UK immigration records. Hungarian immigration is unlikely to hold you like that for something as simple as an incongruous record in UK immigration. Hungarian officials probably don't check UK immigration *as a matter of routine*.

You cannot demand that information be deleted from your immigration record. If that were the case then every illegal entrant would simply demand that the records of their illegal activity be deleted.

If you are convinced that there is an error in your immigration record, then the first step is to get access to your immigration record. This can be done with a [subject access request](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration). The details of how to do it, and how much it costs, are given in the link. If you then find something inaccurate then you will have to work with UK Immigration to get it corrected. This may be as simple as providing documentation to prove that their records are wrong, or it may involved lots of time from an expensive lawyer. In any case we cannot say more about what is involved without knowing the details.

Comment: OP is a UK citizen, so could be expected to have more rights regarding data held by the UK government than a noncitizen / illegal entrant would.

Comment: I believe the linked document is for UK citizens.

Comment: I was referring to your statement "If that were the case then every illegal entrant would simply demand that the records of their illegal activity be deleted."

Comment: As I've said, this is not a big problem for me. However, I'm not so sure about "Hungarian immigration is unlikely to hold you like that for something as simple as an incongruous record in UK immigration. Hungarian officials probably don't check UK immigration as a matter of routine". The officer only had a small hand-held device, which perhaps showed the same simple alert that it would have shown for a serious matter. The officers didn't know English. Immigration data was/is probably shared between the UK and Schengen, so that e.g. Schengen could see if someone had overstayed a UK visa.